# Hyperlink with variables to create a modal box/popup

Tags: javascript, html, css, variables, hyperlink

Like in the title I would like to use a variable inside the hyperlink to use it into the modal window.

I am not using bootstrap, it is a custom code but it works until I try to put some kind of `<a href='#openModal?id=".$VARIABLE."'>`

Is it possible to do that?

Regards

Update:

```
<?php 
            $query = "SELECT * FROM USER";

            $result = mysqli_query ($connection,$query)
                or die ("You couldn’t execute query");

            echo "<div class='admin-table'>
                <table cellspacing='15'>
                        <td><h3>Last Name</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Name</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Phone</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Address</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Postcode</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Date of Birth</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Email</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Password</h3></td>
                        <td><h3>Role</h3></td>
                    </tr>";

            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                {
                extract ($row);
                echo "<tr>\n 
                        <td>$USER_LASTNAME</td>\n
                        <td>$USER_FIRTSNAME</td>\n
                        <td>$USER_PHONE</td>\n
                        <td>$USER_ADDRESS</td>\n
                        <td>$USER_POSTCODE</td>\n
                        <td>$USER_DOB</td>\n
                        <td>$USER_EMAIL</td>\n
                        <td>$USER_PASSWORD</td>\n
                        <td>$USER_ROLE</td>\n
                        <td><a href='admin_user.php?id=".$USER_ID."'>Delete</a></td>\n
                        <td><a href='#openModal?id=".$USER_ID."'>Edit</a></td>\n
                    </tr>\n";
                echo "<tr><td colspan ='15'><hr></td></tr>\n";
                }
                echo "</table></div>\n";
?>


<div id="openModal?id=<?php echo $USER_ID; ?>" class="modalDialog">
    <div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
        <h2>$USER_ID</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is working the modal but its just taking the last id, I have to think another solution to pass the variable.

Many thanks for your help

Update 2:

Thank you very much! Now its working,

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM USER;";
$result = mysqli_query ($connection,$query) or die ("You couldn’t execute query");

//First echo the table with all your data as you want
echo "
<div class='admin-table'>
    <table cellspacing='15'>
    <tr>
        <td><h3>Last Name</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Name</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Phone</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Address</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Postcode</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Date of Birth</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Email</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Password</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Role</h3></td>
    </tr>";
//Fetch all rows for each user
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    extract ($row);
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>$USER_LASTNAME</td>
        <td>$USER_FIRTSNAME</td>
        <td>$USER_PHONE</td>
        <td>$USER_ADDRESS</td>
        <td>$USER_POSTCODE</td>
        <td>$USER_DOB</td>
        <td>$USER_EMAIL</td>
        <td>$USER_PASSWORD</td>
        <td>$USER_ROLE</td>
        <td><a href='admin_user.php?id=".$USER_ID."'>Delete</a></td>
        <td><a href='#openModal?id=".$USER_ID."'>Edit</a></td>
        <div id='openModal?id=".$USER_ID."' class='modalDialog'>
        <div><a href='#close' title='Close' class='close'>X</a>
            <h2>".$USER_ID."</h2>
            <p>You can have additional details here.</p>
        </div>
        </div>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan ='15'><hr></td>
    </tr>";
}
echo"
    </table>
</div>";
?>
```

Comment: This line of code is in php, javascript or just html?

Comment: I am using just html and css to make the modal but it is inside a php code the hyperlink, I am using this tutorial http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/creating-a-modal-window-with-html5-and-css3/

Comment: Then i think that @Ferrrmolina's answer suits you nicely. Try it and if you have any further problems feel free to ask.

Comment: I think the problem is because the id="openModal" from the div and href="#openModal?id=..." from the link are not the same for that reason is not working. But then it is impossible to pass a variable.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think now it will work.

Comment: Nice. If you want a modal for each user then you have to put modal creation in the while loop. If this is the case then say it and i ll post the answer.

Comment: Yes, that would be great

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly. If the provided answer isn't what you want then please explain in detail what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo '<a href="#openModal?id='.$VARIABLE.'">';
```

Update:

```
echo '<td><a href="#openModal?id='.$variable.'">Edit</a></td>\n';
echo '<td><a href="admin_user.php?id='.$USER_ID.'">Delete</a></td>\n';
```

Comment: I am using echo "<td><a href='#openModal?id=".$variable."'>Edit</a></td>\n"; and before that echo " <td><a href='admin_user.php?id=".$USER_ID."'>Delete</a></td>\n";

Comment: I dont think is a problem of single or double quotes

Comment: The modal window open when you click?
$VARIABLE and $USER_ID is set correctly? check printing only the 2 variables first.

Comment: The model window open when is just #openModal, but when is #openModa?id=13 for example is not. The variables are fine

Comment: You have to add the $USER_ID in div html id too!

Answer (score 0):

any reason you can't use onclick ?

```
<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc();">
<script>
 function myJsFunc() {
    //code to open modal
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not using javascript

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

If i have understood you correct you are trying to make a table showing all users and then when the admin clicks at  element a modal pop ups providing additional info for the particular user.

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM USER;";
$result = mysqli_query ($connection,$query) or die ("You couldn’t execute query");

//First echo the table with all your data as you want
echo "
<div class='admin-table'>
    <table cellspacing='15'>
    <tr>
        <td><h3>Last Name</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Name</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Phone</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Address</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Postcode</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Date of Birth</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Email</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Password</h3></td>
        <td><h3>Role</h3></td>
    </tr>";
//Fetch all rows for each user
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    extract ($row);
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>$USER_LASTNAME</td>
        <td>$USER_FIRTSNAME</td>
        <td>$USER_PHONE</td>
        <td>$USER_ADDRESS</td>
        <td>$USER_POSTCODE</td>
        <td>$USER_DOB</td>
        <td>$USER_EMAIL</td>
        <td>$USER_PASSWORD</td>
        <td>$USER_ROLE</td>
        <td><a href='admin_user.php?id=".$USER_ID."'>Delete</a></td>
        <td><a href='#openModal".$USER_ID."'>Edit</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan ='15'><hr></td>
    </tr>";
}
echo"
    </table>
</div>";
//Fetch again the rows to make the modals with the edit info
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    extract ($row);
    echo '
    <div id="openModal'.$USER_ID.'" class="modalDialog">
        <div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
            <h2>'.$USER_ID.'</h2>
            <p>You can have additional details here.</p>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
?>
```

---

---

Old answer before the comments

It seems that single quotes and/or double quotes aren't escaped properly.
Also remember that in PHP string concatenation is made using " . " (dot) and in JavaScript using " + " (plus).

Update 1

I think that if you use the following you will be ok.

```
echo '<td><a href="admin_user.php?id='.$USER_ID.'">Delete</a></td>';
echo '<td><a href="#openModal'.$variable.'">Edit</a></td>';
```

Update 2

Don't forget to add `$variable` at div too so `<a>` and `div id` are the same the same. E.g.

```
echo '<div id="openModal'.$variable.'" class="modalDialog"></div>';
```

Comment: I am sorry but I think that works fine because I am using already <td><a href='admin_user.php?id=".$variable."'>Delete</a></td>\n and works perfect

Comment: echo "<td><a href='#openModal?id=".$USER_ID."'>Edit</a></td>\n";

<div id="openModal?id='<?php echo $USER_ID; ?>'" class="modalDialog">

Like that?

Comment: No, its: <div id="openModal<?php echo $USER_ID; ?>" class="modalDialog"></div>

Comment: Check my answer. Look, whatever variable you have at: href="#openModal'.$variable.'" you have to add it at: id="openModal'.$variable.'" and you are ready!

Comment: I think I got it but now there is another problem, its taking the last id.

Comment: Please edit your question, add all the code for this specific part and i will write down the answer in 2 minutes.

Comment: Yes, the updated 2 is how it works for me, thank you very much